# How to create a script to sync notes to files using Geeknote

Tags: command-line, bash, sync

## The problem

I want to create a directory with my notes from Evernote in files with the Markdown format. I found out that this can be made using [Geeknote](http://www.geeknote.me/documentation/), but for each notebook every time.

How to create a bash script that synchronizes a directory, where each subdirectory is a different notebook, and inside these the markdown files?

*While you make suggestions, I will keep this question updated.*

### Some background commands to start from

The command to two-way sync using Geeknote is the following:

```
gnsync --path ~/Evernote/Ler --logpath ~/.log/geeknote.log --format markdown --notebook ".Ler" --two-way TWO_WAY
```

The command to list my notebooks is:

```
geeknote notebook-list
```

### Partial solution

@RichardAnderson suggested the following code to list and loop into the Evernote notebooks, I tested in my system and it is working. The problem is that the *geeknote notebook-list* command waits for user action during the listing, I also couldn't find a way to circumvent that.

Just create a file with the following content:

```
    #!/bin/bash
    geeknote notebook-list > /tmp/list.txt
    Note_List=$(cat /tmp/list.txt | grep -v Total | cut -d : -f 2)
    for i in $Note_List; do
        gnsync --path ~/evernote --logpath ~/.log/geeknote.log --format markdownn --notebook "$i" --two-way TWO_WAY
    done
```

Don't forget to change to your path.

**ATTENTION!** If you have images or heavily formatted notes in your evernote account, please note that this method can potentially remove formatting and data within notes. So use at your own risk!

### How to solve the last bit?

If you know a way of circumventing the need for user action during the geeknote note-list command, please drop a line below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I went for the bash solution:

```
function sync_notebook {
  gnsync --path ~/Evernote/$1 --logpath ~/.log/geeknote$1.log --format markdown --notebook "$1" --two-way TWO_WAY
}


function sync_all {
  for D in *; do sync_notebook $D; done
}
```

I added these to my `.bashrc`.

The first is just a wrapper to `gnsync`. It takes a single argument, the name of a notebook. The second is a bash loop over all of the folders in a directory. The names of the folders match the names of notebooks in evernote.

Still haven't figured how not to kill pdfs in sync.

Answer (score 1):

I was looking for the same thing. This is what I came up with.

```
#!/bin/bash
geeknote notebook-list > /tmp/list.txt
Note_List=$(cat /tmp/list.txt | grep -v Total | cut -d : -f 2)
for i in $Note_List; do
    gnsync --path ~/evernote --logpath ~/.log/geeknote.log --format markdown --notebook "$i" --two-way TWO_WAY
done
```

You will probably have to press enter a few times after starting. I am not sure how to treat the geeknote notebook-list command to eliminate the need for having to press enter.

Comment: You could try the `yes` command - see `man yes`

Answer (score 1):

I don't know, how to circumvent the need to interact, but I know how to automate it: `expect`. You can install it with `apt-get`. Here's my expect script, which did the trick for me:

```
#!/usr/bin/expect -f

spawn geeknote "notebook-list"

expect "More"
sleep 2
send "j"
interact
```

Then you can use this in place of `geeknote notebook-list`:

```
./geeknote-expect-script > /tmp/list.txt
```